# FREAD row criteria in R

Tags: r

Since I have more than 10gb of data, I am looking to find a way to create a row filter criteria before reading the dataset into R so that the data read would be less than 10gb and the time required would be less. 
Currently I am using the fread and even though it has the select criteria c("a","b"), I was not able to find a row filter critera (e.g. Col A > 2).

Is there a workaround for this in fread?
If not then is there any other way?

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. Do you have a 10Gb CSV file or similar? You can filter out rows from CSV files using tools such as "grep" and "awk", which come as standard on Unix/Mac systems but can be installed on Windows.

Comment: 10GB CSV file. How would I use it on Windows?